# Why doesn't stats.sem() recognize the nan_policy keyword?

Tags: python, scipy

Code:

```
e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
s = stats.sem(e, nan_policy = 'omit')
```

Error:

```
sem() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nan_policy'
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error; 'nan_policy' is a perfectly [acceptable](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sem.html) parameter for `stats.sem()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scipy.stats.sem` only acquired the keyword argument `nan_policy` in release 0.17.0. You are most likely using release 0.16.0 as many people still do, in which case you only have access to the other two keyword arguments `axis` and `ddof`.

[From the release notes for 0.17.0](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.17.0.html#scipy-stats-improvements):

> Many functions in scipy.stats have gained a `nan_policy` keyword, which allows specifying how to treat input with NaNs in them: propagate the NaNs, raise an error, or omit the NaNs.

Unfortunately you'll have to treat NaN-ridden inputs on your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to update to release 0.17.0?

Comment: @TylerAdkins Of course, you can find it in the Python package index [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy).